# preg_replace syntax with wildcard

Tags: php, syntax, preg-replace

I have been trying for a couple of hours. It's simple text (string). Could someone tell me what is wrong with this syntax. Not working

```
$finalcontent = preg_replace('/<h2>.*?<\/div><\/div>/', '</h2>$variable</div></div>', $finalcontent);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your input data and expected output data?

Comment: HTML and regexs are usually a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `DOM` instead of `regex` in order to manipulate `HTML`. 
Using `DOM` you can effectively manipulate the `HTML` document, with the help of [DOMNode::appendChild](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) and [DOMDocument::createTextNode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php) you can insert text coming from `$variable` after the `h2` element.

We get the parent of the `h2` element (`$doc->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->parentNode`) and append a child to it, that will be placed after the `h2`. This child is a textnode created from the input `$variable` (`$doc->createTextNode($variable)`).

```
$html = '<div><div><h2>Hi</h2></div></div>';
$variable = 'Hello Stackoverflow';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$newTextNode = $doc->createTextNode($variable);
$doc->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->parentNode->appendChild($newTextNode);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Results in:

```
<div><div><h2>Hi</h2>Hello Stackoverflow</div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't add variable in single quotes, your second parameter should be in double quotes "$variable" , not '$variable'

You can find very good ref for Single vs double quotes here:
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Adding double quotes will not fix the issue.

Comment: Actually it will. Please prove me wrong, of course, there is a typo also in the regex
<h2> should be added instead of  </h2>, but this is the solution